# add np.int64 function to one of the parameters

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I need to modify the source code by adding np.int64 function to one of the parameters.

Original line:

```
'      indices = expand_dims(indices, axis=0)'
```

New line:

```
'      indices = expand_dims(np.int64(indices), axis=0)'
```

The path of the file is this...

> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/array_ops.py

What is the correct way to make modifications to source code?

Comment: On SO we do encourage users to add their own efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problem, so kindly do add the same and let us know then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With so little information at hand, there's not much we can do to help you.

1. If the line occurs only once (which I could not believe is true, otherwise you wouldn't have posted a question here, would you?), just edit it manually and that's it.
2. If the line occurs multiple times without variations, you can pass the file to the following `sed` command

   ```
   sed 's/indices/np.int64(indices)/2' yourfile
   ```

   which substitutes the `2`nd occurence of `indices` with `np.int64(indices)` **in every line**.
3. If the line changes somewhat from one occurrence to another, then you really need to provide more info.